# Error trying to compile newest Laravel Mix 6 app.js

Tags: javascript, laravel, sass, laravel-mix

I have been using Laravel Mix to bundle my CSS and JS files, but the newest version of Laravel Mix that dropped about a day ago is not working for me for some reason. I'm a noob to using Webpack, but I previously had success on v5, so I don't know what's going on now. I've updated node and npm, cleared my caches, and started everything from scratch.

**HTML**

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Button Name</button>
<div id="myDIV">
    This is a DIV element.
</div>
```

**Steps**

1. Make an app.js source file that has one basic function to toggle a class:

```
function myFunction() {
    var element = document.getElementById("myDIV");
    element.classList.toggle("mystyle");
 }
```

3. npm init -y
4. npm install laravel-mix --save-dev
5. npx touch webpack.mix.js

my webpack.mix.js file :

```
// webpack.mix.js

let mix = require('laravel-mix');


mix.js('src/app.js', 'js');
```

1. npx mix runs, adds dependencies, asks me to run again
2. npx mix runs, compiles app.js to

```
/******/ (() => { // webpackBootstrap
/*!********************!*\
  !*** ./src/app.js ***!
  \********************/
function myFunction() {
  var element = document.getElementById("myDIV");
  element.classList.toggle("mystyle");
}
/******/ })()
;
```

I'm wondering why all the extra code is being injected into the compiled app.js? Is my webpack.mix.js incorrect? I don't have bootstrap installed, so why is it asking for that? The way it is compiling breaks javascript functionality right now, even on a basic experiment like this. It's probably simple, but I'm having trouble identifying what's going on. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: i think the additional stuff will be stripped for production builds. I'm not sure what the comments are for, it might be that webpack uses it to compile faster (only the changed files for instance)

Comment: When I run npx mix --production, the resulting app.js is completely empty. And before in v5 I could run javascript in either dev or production so I think it has something to do with the laravel mix modules not compiling correctly.